# Integration using the Trapezium Rule in C giving wrong answer for certain values

Tags: c

I've written some code to Integrate the function 5x^4 + 4x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float func(float x){
    float a;
    a = 5*pow(x,4) + 4*pow(x,3) + 3*pow(x,2) + 2*x +1;
    return a;
}

int main(){ 
    float numberOfXValues;
    float a = 0;            //lower limit
    float b = 1;            //upper limit
    float numberOfStrips;
    float stripSize;
    float finalAnswer;
    float sumFirstAndLast;  //summation of first and last x value

    while(1){
        printf("Input number of X values:");
        scanf("%f", &numberOfXValues);

        numberOfStrips = numberOfXValues - 1;
        stripSize = (b - a)/(numberOfStrips);                      
        sumFirstAndLast = 0.5*func(a) + 0.5*func(b);

        for (float z = stripSize; z < b; z += stripSize ){
            sumFirstAndLast += func(z);
        }

        finalAnswer = sumFirstAndLast * stripSize;

        printf("%f\n", finalAnswer);
    }
return 0;
}
```

And it works for the majority of values, but the output for 13 and 20 is giving the wrong answer. I've looked through it a few times but can't see what could be causing this.

`Input number of X values:10
5.039070
Input number of X values:11
5.031651
Input number of X values:12
5.026160
Input number of X values:13
6.271982
Input number of X values:14
5.018732
Input number of X values:15
5.016153
Input number of X values:16
5.014071
Input number of X values:17
5.012367
Input number of X values:18
5.010955
Input number of X values:19
5.009773
Input number of X values:20
5.798243
Input number of X values:21
5.007917`

Comment: What are the expected values?

Comment: What are the correct values, and why do you think they are correct?

Comment: It should just tend towards 5. There are lots of numbers other than the two I posted that it isn't working for, eg. 24, 28, 29 and 32.

Comment: BTW, I think your `numberOfXValues` should be integer..

Comment: I've changed numberOfXValues and numberOfStrips both to integers now, still not working though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the exit condition of the inner loop, you compare two floating point numbers. After `numberOfStrips` iterations, it's not guaranteed that `z == b` because of floating point accuracy. It's entirely possible that `z < b` or `z > b`. In the `z < b` case, the loop it executed another time.

You should make `numberOfStrips` an integer and rewrite the loop like this:

```
float z = stripSize;
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfStrips; i++) {
    sumFirstAndLast += func(z);
    z += stripSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance this looks to precision and rounding issues of `float`.
Therefore change `float` to `double`.

For example on my machine I get `6.271982` for an input of `10` when using `float` while I get `5.021983` as result when using `double`.

Moreover you should use an epsilon in floating point comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the line:

```
printf("%f, %d\n", z, z < b);
```

Inside the `for` loop will print the `z` values each iteration along with the loop condition result. The last output of this will be:

```
1.000000, 1
```

Which is pointing that we have already reached the right limit, but still performing the loop body. Literally it is thinking that `1.000 < 1.000`. It can happen when working with float numbers, so in order to prevent it, consider looping on some integer number (`numberOfXValues` for example).